# PostCSS import not importing files inside @media query

Tags: css, postcss, postcss-import

I am trying to have PostCSS import different files for different media queries however imports with media queries are not executed.

Other imports work fine but ones inside of this are not imported.

Example

```
@import "variables.css";

h1 {font-family: var(--font-heading);}

@media (--small-device){
  @import "detailed/small/base.css";
}

@media (--medium-device){
    @import "detailed/medium/base.css";
}

@media (large-device){
    @import "detailed/large/base.css";
}
```

ends up being processed into

```
h1 {font-family: Arial;} /* Variables imported fine */

@media (max-width: 600px){ /* postcss-custom-media working fine */
  @import "detailed/small/base.css"; /* why is this and the two below not imported? */
}

@media (max-width: 12600px){
    @import "detailed/medium/base.css";
}

@media (min-width: 1201px){
    @import "detailed/large/base.css";
}
```

If I bring the import outside the import it is imported fine.%}

```
@import "variables.css";

h1 {font-family: var(--font-heading);}

@import "detailed/small/base.css";

@media (--small-device) {}
```

ends up as

```
h1 {font-family: Arial;}

.item {columns: 3} /* Imported base.css file, so paths are correct */

@media (max-width: 600px){}
```

My postcss config:

console.log("CSS changed. Processing...");

```
var postcss = require('postcss');
var fs = require('fs');

var postcss_import = require('import-postcss');
var postcss_custom_media = require('postcss-custom-media');
var postcss_css_variables = require('postcss-css-variables');
var postcss_discard_comments = require('postcss-discard-comments');
var postcss_autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var postcss_reporter = require('postcss-reporter');

var options = {
    from: 'css/style.css',
    to: 'postcsstest/static/css/style.css',
    map: { inline: true }
};

var css = fs.readFileSync("css/style.css", "utf8");

postcss([
    postcss_import,
    postcss_custom_media,
    postcss_css_variables,
    postcss_discard_comments,
    postcss_autoprefixer,
    postcss_reporter
])
.process(css, options)
.then(function (result) {
    fs.writeFileSync('postcsstest/static/css/style.css', result.css);
    console.log("CSS finished");
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log("CSS error");
});
```

Output from the reported doesnt mention this (only some empty imports).
Is there a plugin or a rule I am not seeing about importing from within media queries?

Comment: Is it possible to add media Query directly in your imported css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the [documentation](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import)?

Looks like you should use

```
@import "detailed/small/base.css" (--small-device);
```

But please consider component-based css structures.
In most cases, including media queries in separate files makes support extremely complicated for other developers.

My best advise would be to have short mixins and sass syntax (with [SugarSS](https://github.com/postcss/sugarss))

```
=r($width)
  @media only screen and (max-width: $width+ "px")
    @content

=rmin($width)
  @media only screen and (min-width: $width+ "px")
    @content
```

So, you can use

```
+r(--mobile)
  some: property
```

SCSS/postcss native is good too

Comment: Thanks for this, I totally missed this in the docs. Works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cant use `@import` inside `@media`

> The @import CSS at-rule is used to import style rules from other style sheets. These rules must precede all other types of rules, except @charset rules; as it is not a nested statement, @import cannot be used inside conditional group at-rules.

[Read Import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40import)

[Read conditional group at-rules.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule#Conditional_Group_Rules)

Answer (score 0):

Insight of imports:

All imports be in js, css should be declared at the top of the file. Many bundlers suggest the same as it is a scalable idea for a comipler to load required dependencies.

The bundling happens in a depth-first approach. Mean,

> If we have a root file say index.js / styles.css, the webpack (typical bundler for front end assets) loads index.js if there is any webpack loader defined for the files matching the pattern it will start parsing / transpiling the code.
>
> Ex: styles.css looks like this

```
@import "variables.css";
```

> Here bundler applies same depth-first approach to variables.css, mean it would start parsing variable.css and start loading first import defined in varibles.css and this process goes on until deepest import and comes back to second line in variable.css after variable.css is completed it would come back to root styles.css / index.js.

However there can be dynamic imports in Javascript as the mentioned loaders (babel-loader, react-jsx transform) will actually transpile and parse the code at NODE layer (A JS Compiler).

Where as,

> For css, there is no processing that takes place at NODE level it bundles and sum's up the css line. So, at this point a media query is not known for the system.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, @import can't be used inside @media or the like.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import,

> @import cannot be used inside conditional group at-rules.

The three conditional group at-rules are (according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule#Conditional_Group_Rules):

> @media,
>
> @supports,
>
> @document

So, just do what you were doing with with keeping the @imports and @medias separate and you should be fine. :)

```css
@import "variables.css";

h1 {font-family: var(--font-heading);}

@import "detailed/small/base.css";

@media (--small-device) {}
```